# How to retrieve a list of Github issues using Postman API

Tags: api, github, postman

I'm using Postman to test pulling a list of issues from my Github

In command line I can do the following

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: token <mytoken>' \
    https://api.github.com/user/issues
```

which I think it returning an empty block:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Tue, 04 Oct 2016 22:01:26 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4988
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1475621615
Cache-Control: private, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Vary: Accept, Authorization, Cookie, X-GitHub-OTP
ETag: "db74aad51113746c20473c4cf2b08bde"
X-OAuth-Scopes: gist, notifications, repo, user
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes:
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Served-By: cee4c0729c8e9147e7abcb45b9d69689
X-GitHub-Request-Id: 520E2ADF:3E4D:3650D52:57F426B6

[

]
```

So I am testing it in Postman, but whilst I can do a simple token GET request, i'm getting the following in Postman

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

Comment: It works with my User Token, but not the Application Token I setup

Answer (score 0):

I had missed adding the scope for the Application Token I had setup

https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/